# jQuery Validation Problems

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to validate 4 fields. The last two have the validation behaving correctly, but the first two don't work. If I enter nothing - the form will still validate.

Here's the jQuery for the method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
            phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
            return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
            phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
        }, "Not a valid phone number");
        $("#advertisePost").validate({
            rules: {
                advRetailerName: {
                    required: true
                },
                advName: {
                    required: true
                },
                advPhone: {
                    required: true,
                    phoneUS: true
                },
                advEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }           
            },
            messages:{
                advRetailerName: {
                    required: "This is required."
                },
                advName: {
                    required: "This is required."
                },
                advPhone: {
                    required: "This is required.",
                    phoneUS: "This is an invalid phone number."
                },
                advEmail: {
                    required: "This is required",
                    email: "This is an invalid email"
                }
            }
        });
```

Here's the actual form itself:

```
 <form action="php/advertisePost.php" method="POST" id="advertisePost">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Retailer Name</td><td><input type="text" id="advRetailerName" name="advRetailerName"/><br/><label for="advRetailerName" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Your Name</td><td><input type="text" id="advName" name="advName"/><br/><label for="advName" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td><td><input type="text" id="advPhone" name="advPhone"/><br/><label for="advPhone" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email Address</td><td><input type="text" id="advEmail" name="advEmail"/><br/><label for="advEmail" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="advSubmit"/>
</form>
```

I've made a half dozen forms just like this flawlessly, but I can't see why there's a problem with the first two fields not following validation rules. Any help?

Comment: There is nothing obvious, jslint confirms the javascript is OK for syntax - which version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've only briefly used this plugin. From what I can remember, all you have to do is add a "required" class to your input elements for validator to check for empty fields.